# Receiving assert failure on Reference Call

Tags: c++, pass-by-reference

(Disclaimer: I have removed the Qt tag in case the problem is in my syntax / understanding of the references involved here)

I have a `foreach` loop with an object `Member`. When I enumerate through the list and try to access a member field, the debugger stops and I get a message:

`Stopped: 'signal-received'` -

The assert failure is:

```
inline QString::QString(const QString &other) : d(other.d)
{ Q_ASSERT(&other != this); d->ref.ref(); }
```

I have checked if the member is NULL, and it isn't. I have tried re-working the code, but I keep failing on this simple call.

Some thing's I missed out. `MemberList` is a singleton (definitely initialized and returns a valid pointer) that is created as the application launches and populates the MemberList with Members from a file. When this is created, there are definitely values, as I print them to `qDebug()`. This page is literally the next page. I am unsure as to how the List items can be destroyed.

The code is as follows:

```
int i = 0;

QList<Member*> members = ml->getMembers();

foreach (Member* mem, members)
{
    QString memID = mem->getMemberID(); // Crash happens here

    QListWidgetItem *lstItem = new QListWidgetItem(memID, lsvMembers);
    lsvMembers->insertItem(i, lstItem);
    i++;
}
```

The Member classes get is as follows:

```
QString getMemberID() const;
```

and the actual function is:

```
QString Member::getMemberID() const
{
    return MemberID;
}
```

The `ml` variable is received as follows:

```
QList<Member*> MemberList::getMembers()
{
    return MemberList::getInstance()->memberList;
}
```

Where `memberList` is a private variable.

---

### Final answer:

I decided to rework the singleton completely and found that I was not instantiating a new Member, rather reusing the previous object over and over. This caused the double reference. S'pose thats pointers for you. Special thanks to [Troubadour](https://stackoverflow.com/users/74465/troubadour) for the effort!

Comment: Does it crash on the first iteration?

Comment: @Troub - Yep. First iteration.

Comment: @QtRunner: I can't see anything wrong in what you are doing so I am beginning to wonder if you have a stale build. If you changed something in the header that defines the `Member` class and not everything that really needed to know about that got rebuilt then you can get this type of problem. Does that sound plausible? If it's easy to rebuild everything you might want to give that a try.

Comment: @Troub - Done that already, about 4 times. I've had it happen before when that was the problem, but the rebuild trick isn't working this time for me. I just don't understand how the pointer references is throwing the error. I will get the exact `assert` that it fails on and let you know.

Comment: @Troub - I've added the assert error. Looks like its losing the reference, but I have no idea how.

Comment: @QtRunner: Looks it's trying to copying the same `QString` back into itself. That's what the assert is checking for. Try omitting the assignment to `memID` and see if the call to `getMemberID` on its own crashes.

Comment: @Troub - I took out the assignment. Still crashes.

Comment: @QtRunner: Ok, thanks. I'm just tossing ideas around here hoping that something will give us inspiration. :) So presumably `MemberID` is just a simple `QString` member of class `Member`? Also, does the loop work correctly if you give it a manually constructed list that you create and populate just before the loop i.e. don't get it from the singleton at all? I've got a simple test app. running now that works fine but of course I have nothing but a string member in `Member`.

Comment: @Troub - Well, works 100% with strings. I can't really work it back with members due to the singleton.

Comment: @QtRunner: I guess it must be in the singleton somewhere then. All I can suggest is to keep querying the first item in the list to find out exactly where it goes bad.

Comment: @Troub - Yup. It was. I decided to rework the singleton completely and found that I was not instantiating a new `Member`, rather reusing the previous object over and over. This caused the double reference. S'pose thats pointers for you. Going to Accept your answer due to the amount of interest shown here, thanks mate. (Sorry, can't +1 due to rep)

Comment: @QtRunner: That's very generous of you, thanks. I'll update my answer with my last comment to make it look as if I helped ;) Glad you got it sorted out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `mem` is not null it could still be the case that the pointer is dangling i.e. the `Member` it was pointing to has been deleted.

If `Member` inherits from `QObject` then you could temporarily change your `QList<Member*>` that is stored in `ml` (assuming that's what's stored in `ml`) into a `QList< QPointer<Member> >`. If you then get a null `QPointer` in the list after calling `getMembers` or at any point during the loop then the object must have been destroyed at some point.

**Edit**

As regards the singleton, are you sure it's initiliased properly? In other words does `MemberList::getInstance()` return a valid pointer or just a random uninitialised one?

**Edit2**

Since we've exhausted most possibilities I guess it must be in the singleton somewhere. All I can suggest is to keep querying the first item in the list to find out exactly where it goes bad.

Comment: Thanks - I updated the question with a new paragraph. Would this not stop the items from being `null` due to the MemberList being a singleton?

Comment: @QtRunner: Hmm, interesting. It does sound unlikely that they would have been destroyed then. After you create each one individually have you tried immediately calling `getMemberID` on it?

Comment: Well, as they're created and added to the list, I have a `toString()` method that I call. The objects are printed out perfectly. I am so stumped.

Comment: @QtRunner: See the edit to my answer. Are you really getting the singleton back from `getInstance`?

Comment: The singleton definitely returns a valid pointer. I've checked this immediately before the call that crashes.